# How to lock scrolling in Xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am looking to stop excel from scrolling past a certain row/column. I have a table that I'm putting into excel, and everywhere outside of the table range needs to have an unlined background. However, by placing an unlined background, this includes the unlined portion in the scroll bar. As such, I would like to prevent scrolling past the limits of the table.

I've tried freeze panes, but the table expands beyond the scope of screen (approximately 50 rows and columns), and freezing the pane will not allow for scrolling across the whole table.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you would do it in Excel.

One way would be to hide all the unused rows and columns. In order to hide a large number of rows you need to use an Excel optimization to hide rows without setting each one (of approximately 1 million rows). To do this in XlsxWriter you can use the [`set_default_row()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-default-row) method.

Columns don’t require this optimization and can be hidden using `set_column()`.

Here is an example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hide_row_col.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write some data.
worksheet.write('D1', 'Some hidden columns.')
worksheet.write('A8', 'Some hidden rows.')

# Hide all rows without data.
worksheet.set_default_row(hide_unused_rows=True)

# Set the height of empty rows that we do want to display even
# if it is the default height.
for row in range(1, 7):
    worksheet.set_row(row, 15)

# Columns can be hidden explicitly. This doesn't increase the file size.
worksheet.set_column('G:XFD', None, None, {'hidden': True})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just for more specifiction, do you have any idea how to accomplish what is done in the excel files from the following link: https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/income-poverty/cps-pinc/pinc-11.html. The natural scroll ends at the bottom of the table, but you can continue further down into infinite white space. On the column side, it just cuts off after the table, but you can still scroll further using the arrow on the bar at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see that spreadsheet isn't doing anything special to prevent scrolling. It is just an Excel feature when the scrolling is reduced when there is a large section of data on the screen (and nothing to the right of it). I'd presume that if you created a similar table with XlsxWriter you would get the same behaviour.

Comment: The second part, the "white space", is created by turning off the worksheet gridlines. This can be done in XlsxWriter using the `hide_gridlines()` worksheet method (see [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/page_setup.html#worksheet-hide-gridlines)).